# command substition for multiline output of command?

Tags: bash

How can I make the following command substitution work?

```
$ time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

$ oldtime="$(time)"
bash: command substitution: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 23: `time)"'
```

I guess it doesn't work because the output of the command has multiple lines, because one line output works:

```
$ oldtime="$(echo hello)"
$ echo $oldtime
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to catch because `time` doesn't write to stdout:

```
$ time > tmpfile

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

and you are not really "timing" anything.

```
oldtime="$(time echo)"
```

doesn't throw an error, but still prints the times to stdout.

You probably want to do something like

```
$ oldtime="$( { time ; } 2>&1 )"
```

Comment: Thanks. why `oldtime="$(time echo)"`has no error, while `oldtime="$(time)"` has? Yes, I am not timing anything

Comment: @Tim I had to search a bit how to catch the output of `time`. I think I have it now (in the update). The error seems to come from not having a command after time **and** not being started interactively.

Answer (score 1):

When run in a subshell like that, you might want to use `times` instead. It is basically the same thing - except that rather than reporting on the processing time for a pipeline handed it as arguments, it instead reports on the processing times used by its parent shell *(read: the command subshell)* and all of its children since its parent shell was invoked - and it should write to stdout.

So you can do:

```
pipeline_out=$(some | arbitrary | pipeline; times)
```

...to grab it all.

Or just to see a usage summary for your current shell session:

```
times
```